# Split Gem (RoR) supports multiple tests/alteratives

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, split, rubygems, ab-testing

I have installed the "split" gem in my rails project.

```
gem 'split', '~> 3.4', '>= 3.4.1', require: 'split/dashboard'
```

I have written an A/B test for an event but want to add one more test at the same point (the "finished" point will be different).

For example, A form has four steps. I want to initiate two A/B tests at step 1; out of which, one test will get completed at step (1) of that form and the other A/B test should be finished when the form is submitted completely (that is, step 4).

Please advise.